# Why this animation doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, jquery-animate, keyframe

I want this div-container hidding (display:none) for 2 sec.

or if you have a better solution, please post it :)but please no jquery or javascript

```
#vcontainer {
  height: 450px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:black;
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  animation: vldng 4s;
  -webkit-animation: vldng 4s;
  display: none;
}

@keyframes vldng {
  0%{display: none;}
  50%{display: block;}
  100%{display: block;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes vldng {
  0%{display: none;}
  50%{display: block;}
  100%{display:block;}
}
```

I hope you can help me! :)

Comment: `display` is not an animatable property. Please check [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-transitions-20091201/#animatable-properties-). One other option you can use `opacity` like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/35cBP/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Opacity` instead of `display`.
but `opacity=0` is different from `display=none`,
in both state you don't see anything.
`opacity:0` make your element acting as a Place Holder, but `display:none` remove your element from view port.